# Does sound card not contain audio processor?

Tags: audio, sound-card

list all PCI devices related with audio:

```
lspci |grep -i  audio
09:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Raven/Raven2/Fenghuang HDMI/DP Audio Controller
09:00.5 Multimedia controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor
09:00.6 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller
```

There are two kind of device : Audio Controller ,Audio Processor.

Show sound cards file directly:

```
cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [Generic        ]: HDA-Intel - HD-Audio Generic
                      HD-Audio Generic at 0xfccc8000 irq 59
 1 [Generic_1      ]: HDA-Intel - HD-Audio Generic
                      HD-Audio Generic at 0xfccc0000 irq 60
```

Only two devices flagged Audio Controller in lscpi shown as sound cards,it infers that

- Does sound card  not contain audio processor?
- Is sound card equal to Audio Controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two Intel HDA audio devices, one for HDMI audio, and one for the others.

This is independent from the [AMD TrueAudio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMD_TrueAudio) co-processor, which is a DSP that can be used for audio calculations. There seems to be a [kernel module](https://linux-hardware.org/index.php?id=pci:1022-15e2-103c-8433) for it, but I don't know which software (if any) uses this module.

All of this hardware is on your CPU/system chipset. None if it is a "sound card" (it's not an external card in the first place). Neither of the two audio devices "contains" the audio processor. Nor is "the sound card equal to the audio processor".